# Table Fragmentation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ola-hallengren, fragmentation

If I execute the following:

```
SELECT dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema', 
dbtables.[name] as 'Table', 
dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
indexstats.alloc_unit_type_desc,
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent as avg,
indexstats.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID('dbname'), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID('dbname')
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

It shows fragmentation level. I then ran Ola Hallengren's index optimise script which obviously reduces indexes.

If I run the query again it now shows high fragmentation in tables without an index e.g:

```
Schema  Table       Index   alloc_unit_type_desc   avg                 page_cont
dbo     tablename   NULL    IN_ROW_DATA            99.4362934362934    8176
```

Should I be concerned by these?

Anything I can do?

Anything I should be doing?

We are experiencing performance issues. I am aware that 2008 is not ideal and that is being addressed.

The datafile is also showing as 220gb but the actual space used is 140gb.

Comment: "Performance issues" is a huge area. Maybe you can pinpoint a specific query or table that's the problem and troubleshoot it. If it's the heap, then consider adding a clustered index in accordance to the queries and operations in which it's involved.

Comment: I recently had a case with a heap with lots and lots of empty space. Only some 6000 rows and a simple SELECT * without WHERE took several minutes. The problem was humongous amount of empty space. This is one of the downsides you can encounter with heaps. I just created a clustered index (on a suitable column) and all was normal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Ola Hallengren's index optimize script does not perform Heap defragmentation.**

In other words table rebuilds are not happening when running the procedure and that is expected.

You could run `ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename REBUILD;` 
to remove the fragmentation.

*This also rebuilds the nonclustered indexes on the heap.*

**Better option than rebuilding your heap tables**

You do have to ask yourself or the application team why you can't add a clustered index to the table.
 as rebuilding the heap uses a lot of resources and is a temporary solution.

If you add a clustered index, that index is included in the Index Optimize script, and fragmentation will be removed when the script runs.

Another option is to add the clustered index and [stop worrying about index fragmentation.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/)

---

> We are experiencing performance issues. I am aware that 2008 is not
>   ideal and that is being addressed.

It could be that it is because of the forwarded records in the heap tables, but at 8167 pages I would say that that is not likely. A starting point could be looking at the queries being executed on your server.

[SP_BlitzCache](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/) can help with finding your worst performing queries.

---

> The datafile is also showing as 220gb but the actual space used is
>   140gb.

This should not be a problem. Apart from disk space you should not be too worried. You are not relying on autogrowth, which is a good thing.

Comment: Alter table <table> REBUILD is supported in SQL Server 2008 onwards so you can do that to rebuild the heap. Tibor Karaszi has a script here: https://karaszi.com/rebuild-all-fragmented-heaps that is of great help